# PHP Laravel Printing - How do i print to other machine

Tags: php, laravel, zebra-printers

I would like to print barcode im using mike42/escpos-php package.
this code was working on my machine

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
class PrintBarCodeController extends Controller
{
    public function printBarcode(Request $request)
    {
         try {
            // Initialize the WindowsPrintConnector with the COM port and baud rate
            $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("COM1");

            // Create a new Printer object and assign the connector to it
            $printer = new Printer($connector);

                    $zplCode = "90809283048";
                    $printer->textRaw($zplCode);

                    // Cut the paper
                    $printer->cut();

                    // Close the connection to the printer
                    $printer->close();

            return response()->json(
                ['message' => 'ZPL code printed successfully',
                ], 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle any exceptions that may occur during the printing process
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Error printing ZPL code: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
}
```

but when I tried to host to a local server and try to print into another machine it does not print.
The printer should be connected to other machine not on hosting server.

I did install the driver of the printer (Zebra Printer) I also use the EPSON Virtual port Assignment Tool to assign the printer port which uses (USB005) to COM1

Comment: Have you tried connecting via IP?

Comment: Have you shared the printer with the server, so that the server can access the printer? If you want the server to print to it, I'd expect you would need to do that, or put the printer on the network so it can be directly accessed.

Comment: just connect to the printer using ip address for example something like this: `$connector = new NetworkPrintConnector("x.x.x.x", 9100); $printer = new Printer($connector);` This will resolve the issue you're facing. Just replace the `x.x.x.x` with the printer ip address `9100` with your port number.

Comment: `use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;` will not work in your case.